Spectrum of two dimensional checkerboard potential
I'm trying to check whether a simple checker-board potential of a discrete Schrodinger operator has a full characterization. I am thinking of an operator $H_{\lambda}:\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^2)\to \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ such that $H_\lambda= A + \lambda V$, where $A$ is the adjacency on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, $\lambda>0$ and $V:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $V(m_1,m_2)= \mathbf{1}_{2\mathbb{Z}}(m_1) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{2\mathbb{Z}}(m_2)$. Essentially $V$ induces a linear projection onto the span of delta functions $\delta_{(m_1,m_2)}$, where both $m_1$ and $m_2$ are even.
This is a periodic Schrodinger operator that seems almost like a tensor product of operators. However, I am only to estimate what the spectrum of such an operator is, using discrete Bloch-Floquet theory.
Since this seems like such a simple potential, I was hoping there would be someone clever in the audience that could help me here.
In the several last questions I asked on this website I had some luck with these sorts of questions, so I hoped that maybe this would be another lucky break for me.
